# Oracle regular expression replace in string ignoring first and last characters

Tags: oracle, regex

regular expression replace in string ignoring first and last characters if they matched

my try

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('TLYU TK0T23T', '[^(\A.)]T[^(.\Z)]', 'Qq' ) contain FROM dual;
```

result

```
TLYUQqQq3T
```

expected result

```
TLYU QqK0Qq23T
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the answer you want:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE 
('TLYU TK0T23T', '([^(\A.)])T([^(.\Z)])', '\1Qq\2' ) contain 
FROM dual;
```

Bobby

Comment: You needed to add parentheses around the strings that came before and after the letter T that you were matching. Then in the replace string you refer to the things in parentheses with \1 and \2. I think that the parentheses within the square brackets are not used for this purpose. So, ([^(\A.)]) is \1 and ([^(.\Z)]) is \2. Is that clear?